# .htaccess all subdomain to a specific file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdomain

I am trying to redirect all traffic to a subdomain to one specific file in the subdomain. This is what I have in the htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/sub.mydomain\.com\/filename\.php" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: And what happens? What do you think the regex `^/?$` does? (It's basically the same as `^$` in this context.)

Comment: Does this "one specific file" use any other local resources (images, CSS, JS, etc.) on this subdomain?

Comment: I tried sub.mydomain.com/otherfile.php and it says page not found. I assumed I made a mistake in this file but didn't understand my error.  I was new to rewrite conditions and not entirely sure the proper format to achieve my goal.  No other resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you need the condition at all (this depends on your setup), but it won't hurt otherwise, so let's just keep it.

This should be a working variant of what you actually ask:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^/filename\.php$
RewriteRule ^ /filename.php [R=301,L]
```

I doubt however that this is what you actually want to achieve. I suspect you *actually* want an internal rewrite, not an external redirection. So something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^/filename\.php$
RewriteRule ^ /filename.php [L]
```

This would leave the visible URL in the browser unchanged, but *internally* rewrite all requests to that php file. Which would remain invisible to users.

Or maybe you even want the combination of both:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^/filename\.php$
RewriteRule ^ /filename.php [L]
```

In general I would prefer to implement such general rules in the actual http server's host configuration, so at a central place, not in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"), but maybe you are using a cheap hosting provider and do not have access to the central configuration.

Comment: Yes, the internal rewrite was what I needed. Thank you!